# Create Arrow Button in Qt Designer?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

In Qt Designer I can only drag the ToolButton from Widget box. The generated code will look like this.

```
    self.toolButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton(Frame)
    self.toolButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 480, 26, 22))
    self.toolButton.setObjectName("toolButton")
```

The button will look like this: [image]

I want it to be an arrow button. For it to be an arrow button, I can do like this:

```
    self.toolButton.setArrowType(QtCore.Qt.UpArrow)
```

My question is, how can I make the arrow button directly in QtDesigner without changing any code ?

Comment: in the settings for the tool button you can adjust the arrow type.

Comment: @alexpdev thanks, I found it. It's in the bottom of the property editor of this widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its in the settings for the tool button on the right hand side

[image]